# Reading json in python separated by newlines

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to read some json with the following format. A simple `pd.read_json()` returns `ValueError: Trailing data`. Adding `lines=True` returns `ValueError: Expected object or value`. I've tried various combinations of readlines() and load()/loads() so far without success.

Any ideas how I could get this into a dataframe?

```
{
    "content": "kdjfsfkjlffsdkj",
    "source": {
        "name": "jfkldsjf"
    },
    "title": "dsldkjfslj",
    "url": "vkljfklgjkdlgj"
}

{
    "content": "djlskgfdklgjkfgj",
    "source": {
        "name": "ldfjkdfjs"
    },
    "title": "lfsjdfklfldsjf",
    "url": "lkjlfggdflkjgdlf"
}
```

Comment: How about splitting using the double newline as a separator, then turn your JSON into a list of dictionnaries? You can then simply use `df = pd.DataFrame(my_list_of_dict)`

Comment: Open the file, add a `[` at the start of the file and a `]` at the end. Then go through make sure the dictionaries are comma separated. (See the answer below.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the ideas internet. None quite solved the problem in the way I needed (I had lots of newline characters in the strings themselves which meant I couldn't split on them) but they helped point the way. In case anyone has a similar problem, this is what worked for me:

```
with open('path/to/original.json', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()  
    data = data.split("}\n")
    data = [d.strip() + "}" for d in data]
    data = list(filter(("}").__ne__, data))
    data = [json.loads(d) for d in data]

with open('path/to/reformatted.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)

df = pd.read_json('path/to/reformatted.json')
```

Answer (score 3):

The sample you have above isn't valid JSON. To be valid JSON these objects need to be within a JS array ([]) and be comma separated, as follows:

```
[{
    "content": "kdjfsfkjlffsdkj",
    "source": {
        "name": "jfkldsjf"
    },
    "title": "dsldkjfslj",
    "url": "vkljfklgjkdlgj"
},

{
    "content": "djlskgfdklgjkfgj",
    "source": {
        "name": "ldfjkdfjs"
    },
    "title": "lfsjdfklfldsjf",
    "url": "lkjlfggdflkjgdlf"
}]
```

I just tried on my machine. When formatted correctly, it works

```
>>> pd.read_json('data.json')
            content                 source           title               url
0   kdjfsfkjlffsdkj   {'name': 'jfkldsjf'}      dsldkjfslj    vkljfklgjkdlgj
1  djlskgfdklgjkfgj  {'name': 'ldfjkdfjs'}  lfsjdfklfldsjf  lkjlfggdflkjgdlf
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! Could you share how you reformatted it?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution if you do not want to reformat your files.
Assuming your JSON is in a string called `my_json` you could do:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

splitted = my_json.split('\n\n')
my_list = [json.loads(e) for e in splitted]
df = pd.DataFrame(my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `jq` then solution is simpler:

```
jq -s '.' path/to/original.json > path/to/reformatted.json
```